# Filter R data frame by columns instead of by rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to filter my data frame so that I get all the columns that have a particular value for given row.

```
DF

  vec1 vec2 vec3
1    a   aa    d
2    b   bb    e
3    c   cc    f
4    1    1    2
```

For example, all the columns that have `1` in the 4th row.

```
DF[4,1]==1 and DF[4,2]==1
# These both evaluate to TRUE. I want those columns.

  vec1 vec2 
1    a   aa
2    b   bb
3    c   cc
4    1    1
```

or all the columns that have something other than `1`   in the 4th row

```
DF[4,3]==1
# This evaluates to FALSE. So this would go in a separate data frame

  vec3
1 d
2 e
3 f
4 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally, the way people use data.frames and their children, this is most often done the other way around. The columns are variables, and the rows are observations of those variables. You can filter a data frame for only those observations (rows) with a particular value for a variable (column). It's not typical, but you could do it the other way around, I suppose.

Filtering by columns instead of rows:

```
DF <- data.frame(vec1 = c("a", "b", "c", 1), vec2 = c("aa", "bb", "cc", 1), vec3 = c("d", "e", "f", 2))
DF
#   vec1 vec2 vec3
# 1    a   aa    d
# 2    b   bb    e
# 3    c   cc    f
# 4    1    1    2

DF[,DF[4,] == 1, drop = FALSE]
#   vec1 vec2
# 1    a   aa
# 2    b   bb
# 3    c   cc
# 4    1    1

DF[,DF[4,] != 1, drop = FALSE]
#   vec3
# 1    d
# 2    e
# 3    f
# 4    2
```

NOTE: you don't NEED `drop = FALSE` if your filter by columns expression is going to have more than one column, but you do if it isn't. The idiom you rely on should account for this, since you may not know ahead of time how many columns will meet your conditions. That's why it's in both statements.

EDIT:
@thelatemail 's suggestion in the comments works as well. For my own style, I don't like to use `c()` for it's attribute stripping effect, but you might prefer not having to type drop.

```
DF[c(DF[4,] != 1)]
#   vec3
# 1    d
# 2    e
# 3    f
# 4    2
```

If you use either of these, you'll want to pay special attention to the commas.

Comment: Slight variation that will always return a data.frame, without needing `drop=` - `DF[c(DF[4,]=="1")]` - `DF[c(DF[4,]=="2")]`

Comment: @thelatemail interesting. Yes, stripping the attributes would change the behavior. I'm not sure I like it as a personal idiom, though. Can't say why exactly...

Comment: @DanHall - `DF[, DF[4,] == 1, drop=FALSE]` implicitly relies on stripping attributes too, as technically you're passing a matrix as the column selection vector. But it doesn't make much difference, your answer is neat and works fine.

Comment: @thelatemail interesting!  That's the second time today I learned something about the internals of the subset operators! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a `dplyr` problem using some combination of `slice` to pick rows and `filter` to pick observations based on certain values, but it's not clear from your question above what you're trying to do. Here are some examples:

```
library(dplyr)
> df %>% slice(n=4)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  vec1  vec2  vec3 
  <fct> <fct> <fct>
1 1     1     2   

> df %>% slice(n=4) %>% filter(vec1==1)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  vec1  vec2  vec3 
  <fct> <fct> <fct>
1 1     1     2    

> df %>% slice(n=4) %>% filter(vec2==1 && vec3==2)
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  vec1  vec2  vec3 
  <fct> <fct> <fct>
1 1     1     2    

> df %>% slice(n=4) %>% filter(vec2==1 && vec3==1)
# A tibble: 0 x 3
# ... with 3 variables: vec1 <fct>, vec2 <fct>, vec3 <fct>

> df %>% filter(vec1==1)
  vec1 vec2 vec3
1    1    1    2
```